# Jenkins: how to graph and threshold numeric results?

Tags: jenkins, plot, graph

I have many Jenkins jobs that output similar sets of numeric results.  I want to extract the results into a format Jenkins understands, graph them, and use them in logic to decide whether to fail the build.  For example:

```
delorean.max_speed_mph = 101.4
delorean.chassis.wheels = 4
```

I want to plot them, but also apply logic to them to decide the state of the build:

```
if (delorean.max_speed_mph < 88)
  state=YELLOW
if (delorean.chassis.wheels != 4)
  state=RED
```

I might have a dozen parameters per job, and slightly different names between each job.

Currently I use the Plot plugin for plotting, but it's tedious to set this up for every job (as the sources have changed the jobs have got out of date), and the setup is slightly different for each one. It also doesn't relate to test results.

I see there is the [Measurement Plots plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin), which looks for XML in the standard out log.  That looks more plausible (the configuration is in my source code, not in Jenkins), but it looks pretty unstructured and I can't threshold it.

The [Performance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) looks a bit more useful in that it expects metadata and is capable of failing the build if the 'performance' is not good enough.  But it's intended to be used with JMeter which, as far as I can tell, is all about web service performance monitoring.  For example JMeter's XML appears to have specifics of HTTP requests baked into it.  I don't see any kind of 'key=value' in there, or any way to test values explicitly: (`value < xx%`) can be done, but not absolute units.  Is it sensible for me to fake up some JMeter XML (missing all the HTTP bits) to feed into the Performance plugin?

Is there some other more generic way of handling numerical results, beyond just counting test failures?

Comment: Tell me if you find something... I'm stuck here too.